Funcionamiento multi-catch para manejo de Excepciones
Sigo estudiando para la OCP Java 11 y quiero comprender bien por que no se permiten clases relacionadas en un bloque multi-catch
Recordamos que FileNotFoundException es una subclase de IOException

Paso a paso:
Invalid try-catch
try {
  //
} catch(IOException e){
  //1
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){ //FileNotFoundException has already been caugh
  //2
}

Explicación: Si en el try se lanza una excepción de tipo IOException (incluida una FileNotFoundException) será atrapada por el primer catch ya que es más genérico y hará que el segundo sea inalcanzable (unreachable) y por lo tanto, Java no lo permite.
Esto se solucionaría fácil invirtiendo el orden de los catch:
try {
  //
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){
  //1
} catch (IOException  e){
  //2
}
//COMPILES

El problema viene al usar bloques multi-catch:
try {
  //
} catch (IOException | FileNotFoundException e) {}

De esta forma (igual que en el primer ejemplo) FileNotFoundException queda opacado y nunca se llegaría a ejecutar y entiendo que Java no lo permita.
Pero, y al revés?
try {
  //
} catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {} //Error: Types in multi-catch must be disjoint

No entiendo por que esto no se pertmite. Si el try lanzase un ZipException (otra subclase de IOException) no sería capturado por el primero (FileNotFoundException) pero si por IOException y no debería haber ningún problema, pero sin embargo, no se permite

Así lo define la especificación:

It is a compile-time error if a union of types contains two
alternatives Di and Dj (i ≠ j) where Di is a subtype of Dj

No puede haber un tipo que sea subtipo de otro en la unión.
Aunque se puede pensar que esas 3 formas son equivalentes, el compilador genera un código diferente.

A catch block that handles multiple exception types creates no
duplication in the bytecode generated by the compiler


Por lo que veo es una norma y punto, no hay que darle más vueltas. Aunque sigo sin entender el por que ya que hay casos donde creo que si que sería útil. Muchas gracias por tu comentario

@Doubtman básicamente es así y ya.
